# Error saying "ActiveX can't create component" with hidden excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba, userform

So, I have an Excel workbook that, when it opens, launches a userform and hides the workbook application window with this code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
 
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MODULE BUTTON").Activate

        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws.Name <> "MODULE BUTTON" Then
            ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
        End If
    Next ws

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MODULE BUTTON").Visible = xlSheetVisible

    Application.Visible = False
  
 Mark1.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

When I close my userform, it saves and closes the hidden workbook with this code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
ThisWorkbook.Save
       
ThisWorbook.Close

End Sub
```

However, the next time I go to launch the workbook, it says "ActiveX component can't create object" on line `Mark1.Show vbModeless`. `Mark1` is the userform. However, once I close it again and reopen it, it opens just fine.

I tried to change the code in the query close to `Application.quit`, which fixed the issue, but it also closes every Excel window and sometimes my users have other Excel files open simultaneously.

Any ideas on what I am missing here?

Edit: I pasted my second code and not the original. The problem I originally had was with ThisWorkbook.Close, and changed it to Application.Quit.

Comment: What about `ThisWorkbook.Close` instead of `Application.Quit`?

Comment: ... or instead all of it just `ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True`.

Comment: Shoot, i mistyped. The problem is that I have it set to ThisWorkbook.Close, and changed it to Application.Quit. Editing post now.